# Create alpha mask from intensity

Tags: compositing-nodes

In Blender Compositor: how can I convert the black in an image to transparency?

Ultimate goal is to `add` one image A over image B without image A darkening image B.

Comment: If you really want to *add*, the you don't need to worry about darkening.. Adding two positive values will always result in a larger value.

Comment: I just noticed - inspecting in the image editor - that my images have pixels with color values below 0.0 and above 1.0, this is very strange. Is there no way to clamp the output of Brightness/Constrast node?

Comment: What I really want is to `replace` rather than `add`

Comment: Then the lighten blend mode sounds like what you want. Regarding your first comment, that is part of the fun of working with floating point images :) if you want to clamp it, a quick way to do that is with a [multiply mix node](http://pasteall.org/pic/76446). Just make sure the other slot is set to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a mix node with the [*lighten* blend mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Lighten_Only)?

[image]

If you want more control, then you can generate a grayscale map and use that to set the alpha with a *set alpha* node:

[image]